# Set JTextField auto changed

Tags: java, swing, set, jtextfield

Have a problem, I have "**yC**" which will change all the time when user press alt + C

The question is how to make JTextField change the value inside every single time the value yC is changes.

```
yT=new JTextField(5);
mainframe.add(yT);
yT.setText(Integer.toString(yC));
window.getContentPane().add(mainframe);
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
```

How change the yC:

```
cor.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                Point b = a.getLocation();
                xC = (int) b.getX();
                yC = (int) b.getY();
                textArea.replaceSelection("X-Coordinates:" + xC + "  Y-Coordinates: " + yC + "\n");
            }

        });
```

Comment: What have you tried? And can you add your code for how you change yC on key press?

Comment: Have edit, check again)

Comment: I assume yC is a numeric field such as an int or double field held by a class. If so, one way to allow other classes to be notified of changes to its value is to make it a "bound" field via PropertyChangeListenerSupport. Only change yC via a setter method, and in this setter method, have the PropertyChangeListenerSupport object notify all listeners. Note that if yC is in the same class as your JTextfield, then your job got easier -- simply change the JTextfield in yC's setter method.

Comment: yC and the method how yC is change in same class but in different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If yC and yT are in the same class, then your job got easier. Consider giving yC a setter method:

```
public void setYC(int yC) {
   this.yC = yC;
   yT.setText(String.valueOf(yC));
}
```

And then **never** set yC directly, but instead **always** through its setter method.

---

**Edit**
One issue you have with your code you've linked to is here:

```
public class Test {

   static JTextField curTimeH, curTimeM, curTimeS, xT, yT;
   Timer timer;
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   static JFrame window;
   static JPanel mainframe;
   static JFrame frameRes;
   static JTextArea textArea;
   static int xC, yC;
```

All of the static fields above should be *instance* fields, or non-static fields. If you state that you did this because the compiler complained about `"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field window"` or something similar, then I'll tell you that you fixed the wrong thing. The key is make key fields such as these instance fields that are used in instance sort of way and not in a static sort of way.

Comment: I understand, the idea about how to do this, but still can get how to implement this to what i'm doing (

Comment: @LoL: if still stuck, then you may want to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) to allow us to experience your problem first hand. Else we'll be forced to guess what might be wrong with your code.

Comment: @LoL: Better for you to compress your code into the smallest compilable runnable example that has no code unrelated to your problem or required for compilability and runnability and post it here in your question.